# ChartArea Title Truncated

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

I'm using the MS Chart control in my C# project and the chartarea titles are being truncated:

[image]

As I make the chart bigger within the window the title sort of toggles between being truncated and not as the window expands.  The chart is anchored right so it expands with the window.

How can I get rid of this truncation?

Answer (score 0):

it hard to see exactly why it happening since you only show the image but you  can try to set truncated labels to false.

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelStyle.TruncatedLabels = False;
 Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.TruncatedLabels = False;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it use Chart Title instead of the Axis Title and dock it to the chart area.

Comment: I tried this and it still would truncate although not quite as often.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up putting a newline at the beginning of the title and it seems to have worked:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = Environment.NewLine + "The Title";
```